# Can an American citizen get an NIE in Spain while on a no-visa 90-day visit?

Tags: visa, spain, identification

I've determined that I need to apply for a [visa de jubilado](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9309/which-visa-for-about-a-year-in-spain-with-flexibility-for-schengen) but interference from other things is greatly slowing the process. So I was thinking of going in January (no visa required for ninety days) and coming back when the application is approved (or denied; hope not!).

Will I be able to get an NIE¹ if I have paperwork showing that I am promised a particular rental house and that I have applied for the visa? To the best of my knowledge, I can't apply for the visa there. I have to spend money to go back to the USA for it (even though they sent the application to Spain for processing!).

My lease is supposed to start in January, but I need the NIE and a bank account to finalize.

¹**N**úmero de **I**dentificación de **E**xtranjero

Comment: [This site](http://www.spanishpropertyinsight.com/legal/spanish-nie-numbers/) suggests that you can, that they can be requested in advance at a consulate, as well as going through [fee-pay services](https://nienumber.com/) I won't assume this is answer as it's [search results such as this](http://suitelife.com/blog/moving-to-barcelona/how-to-get-a-spanish-nie-number-its-kind-of-a-big-deal/)

Comment: Thanks.  It also suggests that I DON'T need the NIE for renting.  But I'll need it nevertheless to handle utilities.  I've filled out the EX-15 to send to the nearest consulate.

Comment: I'm so not an expert as much as able to suss out info; as for sending your goods, have a look at [this shipper](https://www.myus.com/esp/) to get an idea of costs per weight. My other thought is looking into re-positioning cruise ships.

Comment: The shipping issue was on a different question.

Comment: It was, indeed :D; I trust all went well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**.  I had been told by bankers and realtors that to get an NIE, you had to have an address, and to buy or rent a *vivienda* you had to have an NIE and a bank account.  And you have to have NIE and address to get a bank account.

All turns out to be false.  But because I had been told that, I went to the Comisaría to ask.  I knew no one in the area to ask to "loan" me their address.  The lady I spoke to told me to use the address of the hostel I was in.

While waiting for the NIE, I signed a lease for a *piso* without mentioning a bank account or NIE.  And then I opened a bank account without the NIE.  I switched the water and electricity to my name without it.

To get it, I did **not** have to have a visa or photos or a home contract.

Two more "impossibilities":  Most Spanish consulates say that to get a visa you must show them a contract to buy or lease a *vivienda*.  I could not find that requirement in Spanish law, and a lawyer told me it is not a requirement.  (And they will "explain it" to the consulate if I hire them).   It also is constantly stated that you have to apply for the visa at the consulate near your "official residence."  The law is written as if assuming you will do so, but it doesn't explicitly require it.  And one person told me that they did their application in Madrid and got the visa.

UPDATE: make the answer “yes” with qualifications.  In Spain, the law doesn’t mean much unless you actually go to court.  The law says they cannot deny you a NIE unless you are in “irregular situation” which apparently means overstaying your legal visit.  They denied me by *assuming* I had overstayed.  BurgosAcoge wrote a three-page letter quoting various laws and pointing out the easy-to-read evidence of my legal exits and re-entrances and demanding they correct it within five days (the law also requires the process not take longer than five days).

Two or three weeks later, I went in to inquire and got “I don’t know why no one has looked at this.”  Two or three more weeks, I was informed by e-mail **at closing time** that it was approved.  They were nice enough to stay open while I ran to a bank to pay the fee, but then they said I had to come back in a few days to get the actual number.  The next day was my last legal day, but I did get the number on my next trip.

Short version: the answer is yes according to law, but unless you’re willing to make an enemy demanding your rights, it could be “no” in practice.